# How to increase the resolution and the quality of the CanvasRecorder in RecordRTC?

Tags: html2canvas, recordrtc

I have tried to increase the quality and resolution of the CanvasRecorder in [HTML Element Recording using RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/master/simple-demos/recording-html-element.html) but it doesn't change. I need the highest video quality to record CSS animations inside an HTML element. Did I miss something?

**Update:** I have tried to increase the dpi/scale in `html2canvas` library by adding `{scale: 2}` as well but the video is still blurry.

Updated code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ztgqbu6x/

```
var options = {
   type: 'canvas',  // Mandatory STRING
   video: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1280
   },
   canvas: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1280
   },
   timeSlice: 10,

   // used by CanvasRecorder and WhammyRecorder
   // it is kind of a "frameRate"
   frameInterval: 90,

   // used by CanvasRecorder and WhammyRecorder
   // you can pass {width:640, height: 480} as well
   //video: HTMLVideoElement,

   // used by WebAssemblyRecorder
   frameRate: 90,

   // used by WebAssemblyRecorder
   bitrate: 128000
};

var recorder = new RecordRTC(canvas2d, options);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936072/recording-the-web-page-by-using-record-rtc-with-angular pls help on this. Thanks.